# Add a Sound Mute Button to a Video Object

Tags: object, button, video, camera, mute

In Flash ActionScript 3.0. I have added a video Object to the stage by attaching the camera and video classes. I have also created a simple mute/unmute button. I want to embed this sound button into the video object to give clients more options. Is there anyway I can incorporate the mute button into the video object? This is my code: I wont display it all its too but any help here be much appreciated!!

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler);

nc.connect(rtmfp://example);

cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
    var vid:Video = new Video(); 
    camera.setMode(720,540,15,true);
    camera.setQuality(0, 100);

    vid.attachCamera(cam); 
    video.width = camera.width;
    video.height = camera.height;

    addChild(vid);

  function setMute(vol){
   var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1,0);
   sTransform.volume = vol;
   SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
}

  var isMuted:Boolean = false;
  mute_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleMuteBtn);

  function toggleMuteBtn(event:MouseEvent):void{
     if(isMuted){
     isMuted = false;
     setMute(1);

    } else {
    isMuted = true;
    setMute(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the video to the stage, you can do this;

```
video.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.5);
```

or in your situation, something like...

```
function setMute(vol)
{
   root.video.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(vol);
}
```